# How do I control the number of stars in this random star generator?

Tags: python

This is an exercise in the Alien Invasion chapter of Python Crash Course, 2nd edition. We create a star class and fill the screen with randomly generated stars. It determines the space available based on screen width and height, and generates stars to fill that space. But I'd like to generate a specific number of stars, say 100 to 200, randomly generated stars.

Here is the main code:

```
import sys
from random import randint

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from star import Star


class StarsGame:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
                (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Stars")

        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_stars()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_q:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    def _create_stars(self):
        """Create a sky full of stars."""
        # Create an star and find the number of stars in a row.
        # Spacing between each star is equal to two star widths.
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (star_width)
        number_stars_x = available_space_x // (2 * star_width)
        
        # Determine the number of rows of stars that fit on the screen.
        #   We'll just fill most of the screen with stars.
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                                (2 * star_height))
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * star_height)
        
        # Fill the sky with stars.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for star_number in range(number_stars_x):
                self._create_star(star_number, row_number)


    def _create_star(self, star_number, row_number):
        """Create an star and place it in the row."""
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        star.rect.x = star_width + 2 * star_width * star_number
        star.rect.y = star.rect.height + 2 * star.rect.height * row_number

        # Randomize the positions of the stars.
        #  This effect looks much better with a tiny star. If you're curious,
        #  you might want to play around with the spacing a little.
        star.rect.x += randint(-5, 5)
        star.rect.y += randint(-5, 5)

        self.stars.add(star)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.stars.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    sg = StarsGame()
    sg.run_game()
```

Edit:
I had to figure out my actual window size (120 x 79) and then added this loop to the Create Stars function:

```
 # Fill the sky with stars.
        for i in range(20):
            star_x = randint(1,120)
            star_y = randint(1,79)
            self._create_star(star_x, star_y)
```

Comment: you need to make it stop depending on the screen height to determine how many stars. This is not an easy problem to start with as there is no "number of starts" per se, it works out out based on how big your screen is. Try changing the number 2 to a number lower then 2 but above 1

Comment: use number_stars_x = randint(100,200) if you want the number of stars to be 100 to 200.

Comment: It's really not clear what outcome you want or what the difficulty is.  As suggested in other comment, it is easy to pick a random integer between bounds.

Comment: There are solutions posted to these exercises [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/chapter_13/), but there is also more than one way to solve this kind of exercise.